# Unity change SpriteLibrary ass

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I don't quite understand how the project works and how the code compiles and what could be preventing this. I have a code that needs data from SpriteLibrary. I didn't understand how to get the data I need from SpriteLibrary, so I created this method inside SpriteLibrary itself.

```
public void CopyLibraryFrom(SpriteLibrary sourceLibrary)
        {
            foreach (var sourceCategory in sourceLibrary.m_Library)
            {
                var targetCategory = new SpriteLibCategory
                {
                    name = sourceCategory.name,
                    categoryList = new List<SpriteCategoryEntry>()
                };

                foreach (var sourceEntry in sourceCategory.categoryList)
                {
                    var targetEntry = new SpriteCategoryEntry
                    {
                        name = sourceEntry.name,
                        sprite = sourceEntry.sprite
                    };

                    targetCategory.categoryList.Add(targetEntry);
                }

                m_Library.Add(targetCategory);
            }
            CacheOverrides();
            RefreshSpriteResolvers();
```

The first problem I encountered was that Visual Studio automatically deleted this method and any changes I made in SpriteLibrary. But if I canceled the automatic deletion several times, the code would be saved. I put it down to the fact that Unity automatically updates SpriteLibrary and resets it to default. Is there any possibility to fully edit SpriteLibrary with normal saving? Or am I doing something wrong?
I haven't opened Unity for a month and I have errors like "CopyLibraryFrom method is not present in SpriteLibrary" again. I opened it again, but now it says that SpriteLibrary is decompiled and I can't edit it in any way. How to fix it? I'm sure I'm doing it wrong, but how can I do it right? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umpNf.png)

I just don't understand how to edit this now? Or what else can I do to make it work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be (part of) a **Package**.

Unity checks for changes and restores the packages from cache (or downloads if not cached already)

> A package installed from a registry is **immutable**, which means you can’t edit it. If you want to edit a package, you can make it mutable
> by copying it to your Projects folder. This package type is called an embedded package, and it overrides what’s in your package cache.

→ If you really require to modify one of these you could make it an embedded package by [copying it from `Library/PackageCache` into the `Packages`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-embed.html#embed-cached) folder.